# Function Arguments in lists in loop (Bash)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i encountered a problem in my script. I don't know how to call a "Function with Argument" in a "List" in a "Loop".

Here is my **code** :

```sh
    f_test1()
    {
        echo "This is test 1"
    }
    
    f_test2()
    {
        echo "Is this test2 ? $1"
    }
    
    functions_list=("f_test1" "f_test2 \"yes\"")
    
    IFS=""
    for function in ${functions_list[*]}; do
        ${function[@]}
    done
```

and the **output** :

```sh
    This is test 1
    test.sh: line 15: f_test2 "yes": command not found
```

Why `f_test1` works while `f_test2` with the argument `yes` doesn't ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your script as follow:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

f_test1()
{
    echo "This is test 1"
}

f_test2()
{
    echo "Is this test2 ? $1"
}

functions_list=("f_test1" "f_test2 yes")

IFS=""
for function in ${functions_list[*]}; do
    eval ${function[@]}
done
```

Now the output is:

```sh
This is test 1
Is this test2 ? yes
```

**PS**: I removed brackets around `yes` (not strictly required, only for readability) and added `eval` to invoke the method.

Comment: What exactly is the point in writing `${function[@]}`? The variable `function` is not an array, and you could equally well write just `$function`. And, shouldn't it be quoted, i.e. `eval "$function"`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is (another) solution ...

```
f_test1()
{
    echo "This is test1"
}

f_test2()
{
    echo "Is this test2 ? $1"
}

functions_list=("f_test1" "f_test2 \"yes\"")

for function in "${functions_list[@]}"; do
    $function
done
```